# Give an example where the union of two affine subspaces is not an affine subspace

Tags: geometry

I'm really confused with this exercise, I understand what and an affine subspace is, so I tried seeing it with two linear varieties, but when it comes down to writing the example I can't think of how it's going to work or how should I start seeing that it is not and affine subspace.

Let me try something at least:
Call:
$$B_1=a+U,B_2=b+W $$
Then $B_1\cup B_2=\{a+\vec{u}\mid\vec{u} \in U\}\cup\{b+\vec{w}\mid\vec{w} \in W\}$.

So if $c\in B_1\cup B_2$, then $c \in B_1$ or $B_2$.
If we take $a=(0,0), b=(1,1) $ and $ U=\{\lambda(1,1)|\lambda\in \mathbb N\}$,
$W=\{\lambda(0,1)|\lambda\in \mathbb N\}$ then I can conclude something? I don't see how, any hint or correction would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean, like, two lines in the plane whose union is not a line? That's pretty weird. I can't imagine anything like that.

Comment: Say, what about the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis? Their union is $\{(x,y):xy=0\}$. Is that an affine subspace??

Answer (score 0):

You simply can take the particular case of two vector subspaces : it is not a vector subspace, unless one of them  is contained in the other (it is also true for sugbroups).

To see it, take an element in $B_1\smallsetminus B_2$, and an element in  $B_2\smallsetminus B_1$. If $B_1\cup B_2$ is a subspace, does their sum live in $B_1$ or in $B_2$?

Comment: so if the union of the vector subspaces of the affine subspaces is not a subspace, then the union of the affine subspaces is not an affine subspace?

Comment: It is not *in general*. Anyway, a vector subspace is an affine subspace.

Answer (score 0):

$z=1$ and $z=2$ in $\Bbb R^3$.